# Precision accuracy radar

Tags: radar

in radar systems how does one measure the precision and accuracy on a radar?
I'm confused with differen definitions in the references:

Richards define (Principles of Modern Radar: Basic Principles - Chapter 18):

Accuracy = Bias

Precision = Standard deviation

Skolnick define (Introduction to radar systems - Chapter 11):
Accuracy something related to noise and then compare the accuracy with RMS error (which makes sense in definition of richards sice RMS error = $\sqrt{bias^2+\sigma^2}$

Peebles (Radar principles - Chapter 10):

Accuracy = Variance

Which setting should I use in context of Radar Systems?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define what is bias and variance here? Without a signal model, it is not easy to understand your question.

Comment: Skolnick is the older work so to some, would take precedence. terminology isn’t always consistent across all sources so one needs to be careful. you could define accuracy in terms of a confidence interval as well. in reality, performance is usually a function of the environment and measured performance can differ a lot from these equations. the word resolution is just as loaded. the word error can mean different things in classification. people will argue about what is noise and what is interference. Life is but.....

Comment: Going to need more information here: accuracy specifically to estimating what part of a radar system? Range measurement? Doppler measurement? Thermal noise measurements?